# Search for string but with minus substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search for strings from a list but I do not want that value returned if the string contains the substring "banner". How would I do this?

Thus far this is my formula for finding the string

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(D11,10)&"*",$A:$A,0)))
```

I want to alter it so that it excludes strings including the substring "banner"

Comment: Can you use vba? It would be much easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in a two criteria lookup with the ISERROR and [ISNUMBER functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) providing either a match on the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) or not.

```
=INDEX(A1:A99, MIN(INDEX(ROW(1:99)+(ISERROR(SEARCH(RIGHT(D11, 10), A1:A99))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Banner", A1:A99)))*1E+99, , )))
```

SEARCH will not require wildcarded criteria as it provides a case-insensitive partial match search.

Comment: Would I be able to alter this so that I search to check for the string but if the return result equals cell X then look for the next string with this in it?